# How to get a Qt-based app (such as the Media Player example) to play videos on Windows 10

Tags: windows, qt, video

I have a Qt application written in C++, which I've been developing on Linux.

I recently got a new system with a fresh install of Windows on it, installed Qt 5.12.9 with Qt Creator 4.12.2 and the bundled MinGW.

My application builds and runs, but it has a video player element, and this doesn't work. I wondered if it was something special I was doing with my application, so I loaded up the 'Media Player' example.

The example doesn't work either - when I try to play a video file, I get the following in the console:

```
Supported audio roles:
qt.multimedia.plugins.directshow: Failed to connect the audio sample grabber
qt.multimedia.plugins.directshow: Unable to connect the video probe!
DirectShowPlayerService::doRender: Unresolved error code 0x80040266 ()
qt.multimedia.plugins.directshow: Failed to connect the audio sample grabber
qt.multimedia.plugins.directshow: Unable to connect the video probe!
DirectShowPlayerService::doRender: Unresolved error code 0x80040266 ()
```

Do I need to install some codecs or something?
I've not built Qt from source before, and would rather avoid trying to do so if possible.

Is there something I can do to get Qt playing video on Windows 10 'out-of-the-box'?

Comment: install https://codecguide.com/download_kl.htm

Comment: @eyllanesc Installing codecs did the trick - feel free to post it as an answer that I can accept. I thought Windows might have progressed a little in the decade since I last used it and maybe installing codecs would either not be needed, or would be automated, but... no.

Comment: @eyllanesc The marked duplicate has no accepted answer, the error messages aren't the same, and the problem includes code written by the OP whereas this question relates to a bundled sample project. While one of the unaccepted answers on the other question mentions installing codecs, I don't see that having a similar possible solutions makes the question a duplicate. I did google the problem before asking here and If I could have found the linked question with the error messages available to me, I wouldn't have asked this one. I'm happy to answer this question myself if you'd prefer.